# Gradle override default 'artifactId' of a zip archive

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm uploading some `my-libs.zip` to S3 and not able to get the syntaxes to override default `artifactId`. Currently the `artifactId`, it is picked up is `project.name` from `settings.gradle`

**Note:** I don't want to change my `project.name` in `settings.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

artifacts {
    someArtifact file: file('image/my-libs.zip'), name: 'my-libs', type: 'zip'
}

uploadSomeArtifact {
    description 'Uploads some artifact.'
    group = "com.mypackage"
    version = "dummy-SNAPSHOT"
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "s3://my-mvn-repo/snapshot/com/mypackage"
            authentication {
                awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for some reason you apply both the [`maven` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) and the [`maven-publish` plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html). Both plugins do basically the same, but the first one was deprecated a long time ago. You should decide which plugin to use and I suggest to use the `maven-publish` plugin.

---

Nevertheless, lets take a look at the documentation of the old `maven` plugin. It says:

> **Maven Element:** `artifactId`
> **Default value:** `uploadTask.repositories.mavenDeployer.pom.artifactId` (if set) or `archiveTask.archiveBaseName`

And later:

> When you set the `archiveTask.archiveBaseName` property to a value other than the default, you’ll also have to set `uploadTask.repositories.mavenDeployer.pom.artifactId` to the same value. Otherwise, the project at hand may be referenced with the wrong artifact ID from generated POMs for other projects in the same build.

Here, [`mavenDeployer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler:mavenDeployer(org.gradle.api.Action)) refers to a deprecated method that gets added to the `RepositoryHandler` behind `repositories`. It seems like it is required to use this deprecated way to specify the target repository instead using the `maven` method you used. Sadly, there is probably no way to use the AWS authentication and the `s3` protocol with this old interface.

---

Let's now take a look at the new `maven-publish` plugin. With this plugin, you no longer define artifacts and configure `Upload` tasks. Instead, you define publications and repositories and the plugin will generate a task for each combination of a publication and a repository:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        myLibs(MavenPublication) {
            groupId = 'com.mypackage'
            artifactId = 'my-libs'
            version = 'dummy-SNAPSHOT'
            artifact (file('image/my-libs.zip')) {
                classifier 'src'
                extension 'zip'
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 's3://my-mvn-repo/snapshot/com/mypackage'
            authentication {
                awsIm(AwsImAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `repositories` part stays the same and the `publications` part allows you to define the `artifactId` in the same way as the `groupId` and the `version`.